# Drop Down List in .NET Windows application

Tags: .net

I have a dropdown list which contain "HR", "Test", and "DEV". I want on the basis of selection "HR", "Test", and "DEV" the second dropdown values will display.

```
private void additems()
{
    //Controls.Add(cmbpackage);
    cmbpackage.Items.Add("HR");
    cmbpackage.Items.Add("Test");
    cmbpackage.Items.Add("DEV");
    addmodules();
}
private void addmodules()
{
    if (cmbpackage.SelectedItem =="HR")
    {
        cmbmodule.Items.Add("ModuleHR1");
        cmbmodule.Items.Add("ModuleHR2");
        cmbmodule.Items.Add("ModuleHR3");
    }

    if (cmbpackage.SelectedItem == "Test")
    {
        cmbmodule.Items.Add("ModuleTest1");
        cmbmodule.Items.Add("ModuleTest2");
        cmbmodule.Items.Add("ModuleTest3");
    }

    if (cmbpackage.SelectedItem == "DEV")
    {
        cmbmodule.Items.Add("ModuleDEV1");
        cmbmodule.Items.Add("ModuleDEV2");
        cmbmodule.Items.Add("ModuleDEV3");
    }

}
```

Comment: then what is the question? what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: values are not populating in "cmbmodule" dropdown while selecting the values (HR, Test, DEV) from "cmbpackage" dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You should register to the SelectedIndexChanged event of cmbPackage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook into the SelectedIndexChanged event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks to all, now I am getting the dropdown value change on the selection of first dropdwon. PFB the source code.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestExcel
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cmbpackage.Items.Add("---Please Select---");
            cmbpackage.Items.Add("HR");
            cmbpackage.Items.Add("Test");
            cmbpackage.Items.Add("DEV");
        }

```
    private void cmbpackage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedValue = cmbpackage.SelectedIndex.ToString();            

        if (selectedValue == "1")
        {
            cmbmodule.Items.Add("ModuleHR1");
            cmbmodule.Items.Add("ModuleHR2");
            cmbmodule.Items.Add("ModuleHR3");

        }

        else if (selectedValue == "2")
        {
            cmbmodule.Items.Add("ModuleTest1");
            cmbmodule.Items.Add("ModuleTest2");
            cmbmodule.Items.Add("ModuleTest3");
        }

        else
        {
            cmbmodule.Items.Add("ModuleDEV1");
            cmbmodule.Items.Add("ModuleDEV2");
            cmbmodule.Items.Add("ModuleDEV3");
        }

    }

}
```

}

Now I want to make index 0. I mean "Please Select" will load at the time of page load only and not by clicking on "cmbpackage" dropdown.

Also I want to change the drop dwon values of "cmbmodule" based on selections on the cmbpackage dropdown. Currently its changing but all the values are getting stored in the "cmbmodule" dropdown.
I want if I select "HR" only ModuleHR1, ModuleHR2, ModuleHR3 will display and same for rest "Test" and "DEV".